# Russian Letters in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, moviepy

I am using moviepy to make some videos. I am using Beautifulsoup to scrape the text.

I need a Russian text clip to appear on the screen with the video. My code works fine for languages like English and Esperanto.

How can I solve this problem?

After the scrape, the type is class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'

This is what I have tried so far.

**Attempt one:**

```
t = ''.join(t.split()) # remove extra whitespaces
t = t.encode("utf-8")
```

The type is class 'str' and the text prints to the terminal perfectly but the Russian letters on the text clip within the video are represented by question marks.

**Attempt two:**

```
t = ''.join(t.split()) # remove extra whitespaces
t = unicode(tag.string) # recommended by bs4
```

Prints to terminal perfectly but when rendering I get this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position...

**Attempt three:**

```
t = ''.join(t.split()) # remove extra whitespaces
t = unicode(t)
```

Prints to terminal perfectly but when rendering I get this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position...

**Attempt four:**

```
t = ''.join(t.split()) # remove extra whitespaces
t = unicode(t, "utf-8")
```

Doesn't even reach the rendering stage - prints to terminal perfectly but I get this error: TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @ Joost I am using Python 2.7.6

Comment: You might want to give Python 3 a try, then. Unicode support in strings is one of the things that was changed quite heavily; in Python 3, `str` is a unicode string by default. moviepy seems to work fine in Python 3.

Comment: I think the problem is with moviepy